# Node contents when placing a node on path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, decorations, tikz-path

In TikZ one can specify a node by a command like

```
\path (0,0) node[node contents=A];
```

This is very useful if one wishes to apply a command to the text in the node, say, to avoid writing

```
\node at (0,0) {\contour{red}{A}};
```

and simply set

```
\path (0,0) node[node contents={\contour{red}{A}}];
```

(which comes very handy when used repeatedly!)

However, there are some restrictions in the syntax, because the parsing of the command stops after `node contents` is found. In particular, this seems to prevent one from placing such a node on a path by means of `decorations.markings` library. Below is the minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (.5,0) node[node contents={A}];
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with \node {B};}] (0,-1) to (1,-1);
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with \node[node contents=C];}] (0,-2) to (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The last command raises an error "`Paragraph ended before \tikz@fig@scan@options was complete. ...node[node contents=C];}] (0,-2) to (1,-2);`"

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that `node contents` has flaws, in this case you are just lacking braces. In general you can often use `execute at begin node` to add something to the node contents, this key has, according to what I find, less flaws.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (.5,0) node[node contents={A}];
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with \node {B};}] (0,-1) to (1,-1);
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
{\node[node contents=C];}}] (0,-2) to (1,-2);
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
{\node[execute at begin node=D]{};}}] (0,-3) to (1,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just put the code between braces.

```
 with {\node {B};}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (.5,0) node[node contents={A}];
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\node {B};}}] (0,-1) to (1,-1);
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[node contents=C];}}] (0,-2) to (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```